# Tensorflow Error when using tf.gradients: TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just started learning `tensorflow` and came across the following error when using the `tf.gradients` functions. Given below is the code and error for `tf.gradients`.

**Python Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ =='__main__':

    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "0"

    w1 = tf.Variable([[1, 2]])
    w2 = tf.Variable([[2], [1]])

    res = tf.matmul(w1,w2)

    grads = tf.gradients(res, [w1,w2])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        print(sess.run(res))
        re = sess.run(grads)
        print(re)
```

**Error:**

```
[[4]]
    re = sess.run(grads)
  File "/home/BH/fyn123456/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/BH/fyn123456/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/home/BH/fyn123456/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 471, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/home/BH/fyn123456/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 261, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/home/BH/fyn123456/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 370, in __init__
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/home/BH/fyn123456/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 370, in <listcomp>
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/home/BH/fyn123456/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 258, in for_fetch
    type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow : TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50776712/tensorflow-typeerror-fetch-argument-none-has-invalid-type-class-nonetype)

Answer (score 0):

My variables are of integer types (because you initialize them with integers) and mathematically there is no gradient defined on integer types so I cannot evaluate them.